# Scale vertices by vertex

Tags: vertices, scale

When i scale chosen vertices of my mesh, they scaled by their center. I want scale chosen vertices by some of vertex.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can change the pivot point to do that.

For instance, here set it to the active element (last selected):

[image]

You can also set the 3D cursor as pivot point if you want to scale from a specific location.